# Query using date range doesn't work for specific data

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates

I have a spreadsheet (URL below). I've set up a query to make sure I understand how to do a query with a date range. Then I tried to create a similar query on the "real" data. The "Week 1" worksheet feeds the "Week 1 data" worksheet, where I manipulate the data and it contains the query. The data range query returns no results. All other queries work.

[my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xpQvI47pcEbNubMxO_gqp516Z5rawZJ3c5EFQqgMAM8/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: its because dates in E column are not recognized as dates by query (this can be checked if you set Automatic formatting for E column)

Comment: Bummer.  I thought about that and tested all of the dates involved using the =isDate() formula and it returned all true values.  I also tried replacing the data in column E with =DateValue() functions and the query still didn't work.

Comment: half true... yes, E colum "does" have dates, but they are not full dates. meaning 'Week 1'!D$3 is in the format `3/4`. so you import it as  `3/4` and internally convert it to `3/4/2019` by using cell formatting, but QUERY still sees it as `3/4`

Comment: So, the query uses the format of the data and not the underlying data?

Comment: yes, in this case

Comment: Are there any other similar cases with other data types?

Comment: sometimes range for query needs to be formatted with `TO_TEXT()` formula. happens when range is already output of other calculations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
={B1:F1; QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA({B2:D, TO_DATE(VALUE(E2:E)), F2:F}), 
         "select * where Col4 >= date '"&TEXT($G$1,   "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
                     and Col4 <= date '"&TEXT($G$1+5, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'", 0)}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VALUE(
 {B1:F1; QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(TO_TEXT({B2:D, VALUE(E2:E), F2:F})), 
         "select * where Col4 >= '"&VALUE(G1)&"' 
                     and Col4 <= '"&VALUE(G1)+5&"'", 0)}),
 {B1:F1; QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(TO_TEXT({B2:D, VALUE(E2:E), F2:F})), 
         "select * where Col4 >= '"&VALUE(G1)&"' 
                     and Col4 <= '"&VALUE(G1)+5&"'", 0)}))
```

[image]